# Подскажите плагин для WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день всем, есть сайт с дипломами [diplom-base.ru](http://diplom-base.ru) там дипломы добавлены просто как заметки, есть ли плагины позволяющие сделать как бы свой формат записи? Что бы можно было создать поля напр. "Тема", "Тип" и т.д. что бы потом можно было по  этим полям сортировать, фильтровать.. и желательно импортировать и экспортировать

Comment: Пропишите статьям метки и рубрики и через админку добавьте соответствующие виджеты.

Answer (score 2):

Это все делается через саму панель управления

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите Custom Post Type в кодексе WordPress.
С помощью этих самых custom post type возможно все, что вы описали выше.
UPD. Единственно, CPT это с родни создания своего плагина. Если вы не хотите лезть в код, тогда это не решение.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой плагин:
[Custom Content Type Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/)

Дает делать все, что вы описали и не требует много знаний.